# Ways to convey Imperfectiveness in English?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

- How did you spend last year?
- I (build) my house

I want to convey the idea that I was occupied with building my house, but I do not want to state that I succesfully finished it.
Obviously, the combination of the verb "build" and singular object would stress the action was completed fully and sucessfully and I had a complete house last year.

What are the ways to remove perfectiveness from this utterance?

I can think of the following:

**I was building** my house the whole year (natural? doesn't it require more sentences?)

**I worked on** building my house

**I was busy** building my house

**I spent** the whole year building my house

**I built houses** (would it work to use the plural? albeit with a big change in meaning, of course)

**I built** my house **until** the very end of the year (probably unnatural?)

What other constructions could you suggest that would remove perfectiveness from this utterance or from any other?

Comment: "I was working on my house" if the person knows you have been building your own house. Otherwise you might say "I was working on the house that I'm building."

Comment: is it possible to answer
"I was building the house I told you about"?
Because if it's possible and natural with "last year" I don't understand why we don't ask people "What were you doing yesterday?" or "I was studying English yesterday" - these sentences are much less common than "What did you do yesterday?' and I studied English yesterday". "What did you do last summer?" - "We mainly fixed cars, swam in the sea and played football". Maybe this anti-perfective use of Past. Cont is only possible with verbs like "build" that are perceived as complete actions by default?

Comment: If asked _how you spent_ a particular period of time, it's natural to answer "[I spent it] doing X". I would find it more natural to answer the question about last summer with "We spent most of our time fixing cars, swimming in the sea and playing football."

Comment: ***imperfectiveness*** [has virtually no currency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=imperfectiveness%2Cimperfection&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimperfectiveness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimperfection%3B%2Cc0) by comparison with ***imperfection***

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by imperfection, but the original term is "imperfective" and "perfective" (not to be confused with perfect/imperfect), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperfective_aspect I thought the closest noun from "imperfective" would be "imperfectiveness"
 that's why I used it in the title

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting one because we don't have a solely grammatical way of unambiguously conveying imperfectiveness. If you really want a shorter alternative to "but I didn't finish", which would always work, I would suggest terms for progress and work:

> I made progress on (building) my house.

> I got closer to finishing my house.

> I worked on building my house.

> I got my house about half (a third, two thirds, etc) of the way done.

Even "I was building" and "I was busy building" fail to convey that you didn't finish.

> What were you doing last year? I was writing my PhD thesis. (And now it's done.)